# .jsbeautifyrc does not accept "\crlf" as eol

Tags: js-beautify

I am using this config with jsbeautify 1.10.2 in Windows 10.

```
{
  "indent_size": "2",
  "indent_char": " ",
  "max_preserve_newlines": "1",
  "preserve_newlines": true,
  "keep_array_indentation": false,
  "break_chained_methods": false,
  "indent_scripts": "normal",
  "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline",
  "space_before_conditional": true,
  "unescape_strings": false,
  "jslint_happy": false,
  "end_with_newline": false,
  "wrap_line_length": "160",
  "indent_inner_html": false,
  "comma_first": false,
  "e4x": false,
  "indent_empty_lines": false,
  "wrap-attributes": "force-aligned",
  "end-with-newline": "true",
  "eol": "\crlf"
}`
```

And calling jsbeautity in this way:

```
js-beautify --config ./.jsbeautifyrc --replace ./apps/**/*.html
```

It throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 599
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at exports.parse (c:\center\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:54:19)
    at exports.json (c:\center\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:70:10)
    at module.exports (c:\center\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:17:15)
    at Object.exports.interpret (c:\center\node_modules\js-beautify\js\lib\cli.js:279:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\center\node_modules\js-beautify\js\bin\js-beautify.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
Error while loading beautifier configuration.
Configuration file chain included:
c:\center\.jsbeautifyrc
c:\center\.jsbeautifyrc
c:\center\node_modules\js-beautify\js\lib/../config/defaults.json
```

if I remove the `eol` key it works but of course it sets the end of line in a way I do not want to.

I have tried with `\\crlf` `/\crlf` and `crlf`. But that just put that exact test in each new line.

Is this a know issue? I am declaring it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol for carriage return is \r (ASCII 13) and for linefeed is \n (ASCII 10).
Try:

```
"eol": "\r\n"
```

CRLF is merely the abbreviation.